# Bootstrap Modal, calling Action Result method on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I need help.

In my view I have a file picker which will load a file in a certain table in my database, on button click it calls a bootstrap modal to ask the user if they are uploading more files.

My View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {

            <div>
                @*@Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" }) <br />*@
                <input type="file" name="file" accept=".csv" />
                @*<input type="submit" value="Upload New Accounts File" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="Confirm()" />*@
                <input type="submit" value="Upload New Accounts File" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDialog" />
                @ViewBag.Message
            </div>
        }
```

My Modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Confirmation Required</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Do you have more files to upload?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult UploadFile()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string confirm_value)
        {
//TODO
//TODO
}
```

My question is the following:

Before having the modal in place, when I click this button "Upload New Accounts File" the file gets loaded to the database, but now its calling the modal. When the user clicks yes on the modal I would like to load the file to the database but I have no clue how.

Please help.

Comment: Is your modal inside the from?

Comment: The modal is not inside the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for doing it like below:

**Modal (Add onclick to button)**

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" onclick="upload()" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
     ...
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function upload() {
    var fdata = new FormData();

    $('input[name="file"]').each(function(a, b) {
        var fileInput = $('input[name="file"]')[a];
        if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
            fdata.append("fileUpload", file);
        }
    });


    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/UploadFile/Upload',
        data: fdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(e) {
            // Do success process
        }
    });
}
```

**Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file) {
    //TODO
    //TODO
}
```